# invalid suffix "b020000.usdhc" on integer constant

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to do unbind a Linux driver from C file using below code

```
fp = popen("echo -n "5b020000.usdhc" > 
/sys/devices/platform/5b020000.usdhc/driver/unbind","r");
```

When I try to compile, I got below error.

```
error: invalid suffix "b020000.usdhc" on integer constant
```

How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: no issue with quotes.

Comment: You have to escape the double quotes inside a string. `popen("echo -n \"5b020000.usdhc\" > /sys/devices/platform/5b020000.usdhc/driver/unbind","r");`

Comment: It looks like you are mixing shell and C. That won't work. Also, it looks like you are trying to write to the file, but you are opening it read-only with `"r"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a double-quoted string inside C string without *escaping* them:

```
fp = popen("echo -n \"5b020000.usdhc\" > /sys/devices/platform/5b020000.usdhc/driver/unbind","r");
//                  ^^              ^^
// Note the escaped double-quotes here
```

Without the quotes you have the string `""echo -n "`, followed by the invalid number `5b020000.usdhc`, followed by the string `" > /sys/devices/platform/5b020000.usdhc/driver/unbind"`.

Though in this specific case shown in the question there's no need for the nested quotes at all.